# Strange behaviour of preg_replace and sql select

Tags: mysql, regex, foreach, preg-replace, preg-match-all

```
      preg_match_all('#\<td id=\"(.*)\"  class=\"(.*)column(.*)\>(.*)\<\/td\>#i', $htmlcontent, $matches);
  $output = $htmlcontent;
  foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match.",";
    $ressql = "SELECT * FROM var WHERE varimportedindex = '".$match."' AND projectid = '".$pid."' AND sheetName = '".$sheetName."'";
    $result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM var WHERE varimportedindex = '".$match."' AND projectid = '".$pid."' AND sheetName = '".$sheetName."'");
    $rowoperation = $result2->fetch_assoc(); //<-- HERE
    #echo $rowvalue = $rowoperation['varvalue'];
    $output = preg_replace("#\<td id=\"(.*)\"  class=\"(.*)column(.*)\>(.*)\<\/td\>#i", "<td id='\\1'  class=\"\\2column\\3\"><input type='input' id='\\1' name='\\1' value='".$rowvalue."'>\\4</td>", $output);
  }
  echo $output;
```

Ok, i can not find PROBLEM there, but if i deactivate replacement row HERE everything works fine. But when i activate it, replacement is not working anymore.

Can someone find the problem with these lines?

Thank you so much.

Regards,
Olaf

Answer (score 0):

```
// Olaf, please edit your question to display a sample input value for $htmlcontent
if(!preg_match_all('#\<td id=\"(.*)\"  class=\"(.*)column(.*)\>(.*)\<\/td\>#i',$htmlcontent,$matches)){
    echo "<div>No match</div>";
}else{
    $where_ext=implode("' OR `varimportedindex`='",$matches[1]);
    $query="SELECT * FROM `var` WHERE projectid='{$pid}' AND `sheetName`='{$sheetName}' AND (`varimportedindex`='{$where_ext}') ORDER BY varimportedindex;";  // only run one query
    if($result=$db->query($query)){
        $pattern="#\<td id=\"(.*)\"  class=\"(.*)column(.*)\>(.*)\<\/td\>#i";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<div>vii={$varimportedindex} & vv={$row["varvalue"]}</div>";
            // Olaf, please state what $varvalue's value might be
            $replace="<td id='\\1' class=\"\\2column\\3\"><input type='input' id='\\1' name='\\1' value='{$row["varvalue"]}'>\\4</td>";
            $output=preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$output);
        }
        echo "<div>{$output}</div>";
        // Olaf, please edit your question to display your expected result based on your sample $htmlcontent
    }else{
        echo "<div>{$db->error}</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlafK. I am not sure if I have fixed your issue by refining your general code structure.  If not, you will need to provide more information in your question, please read the comments in my code.  Let's work together to find some resolution for this question.  If you, more importantly, no longer care about this question, please delete it so no SO users waste any time on trying to help you.